# admin and login routes doesn't work on spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have a spree application that runs perfect on my local machine with the development environment.

I managed to deploy the app to a vps using capistrano, everything works just fine.

I can get to http://mydomain.com and I see the empty store. Looks good so far.

The thing is that when I try to go to http://mydomain.com/login or http://mydomain.com/admin

The browser gets no response and I see no trails on apache's error log nor in the app's production log.

Here are the routes taken from rake routes:

```
admin_search_users GET    /admin/search/users(.:format)                                              spree/admin/search#users
login GET    /login(.:format)                                                           spree/user_sessions#new
```

curl output:

> → curl -I http://mydomain.com/login
>   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>   Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 01:41:22 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
>   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   X-Request-Id: 8e55b59d-5f76-4136-bf2c-a54d427025f6
>   X-Runtime: 0.009355
>   X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.36
>   Set-Cookie: request_method=HEAD; path=/
>   Set-Cookie: _artemia_session=UnBvNHdLMWxCL1pMcUdleWhsZXRZNG5sUnd2eDdKS2JYNldreHUwTnZpMFdpVGYvTXoxMjBOOTFmWmNyTVdmRVE1TTUrNy90eDhTejNtanRvZWdrS0FvNlIzVGYwbDN2NnpMbldONEJYVE9TSzNndDZQemhHRzRiWmNxMWJ4MStzOE93cjFjNEFZWUxKZXdUakFlWWJyb1VaK3pWdFRVc0hKL0Fjb1JHb0lnPS0tRDhTa0tQdGh2WkNYK0dHSlhoZmhFQT09--5eaabba7b19b66079a20bf24da9cfb97b2458287; path=/; HttpOnly
>   Location: https://mydomain.com/login
>   Status: 301 Moved Permanently
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

curl hit on rails production log:

> I, [2014-01-27T01:41:22.847239 #31960]  INFO -- : Started HEAD "/login" for 190.134.31.176 at 2014-01-27 01:41:22 +0000
>   I, [2014-01-27T01:41:22.849285 #31960]  INFO -- : Processing by Spree::UserSessionsController#new as */*
>   I, [2014-01-27T01:41:22.855083 #31960]  INFO -- : Redirected to https://mydomain.com/login
>   I, [2014-01-27T01:41:22.855384 #31960]  INFO -- : Filter chain halted as # rendered or redirected
>   I, [2014-01-27T01:41:22.855688 #31960]  INFO -- : Completed 301 Moved Permanently in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: Please add the browser's Javascript console output and your routes.rb and `rake routes` output.

Comment: I've added the rake routes output for both admin and login routes.
Javascript console don't show anything.

Weird is that http://mydomain.com/cart and http://mydomain.com/products both work just fine.

Comment: What does the output of `curl -I http://mydomain.com/login` say? Does the server request show up in the logs?

Comment: Added curl output as well as rails production log for the request

Comment: Ahh, it redirected to your secure server. `Location: https://mydomain.com/login
Status: 301 Moved Permanently`. What is the output of `curl -I https://mydomain.com/login`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route is being re-directed to your secure server. Do you have your SSL/HTTPS server configured correctly? Do you have the following setting in `config/environments/production.rb` and do you want it set?

```
# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
config.force_ssl = true
```

Comment: I don't have ssl configured in the server and the production.rb has that line commented:
`# config.force_ssl = true`

Comment: I am accepting your answer since you pointed me to the right direction. I actually fixed this by adding
`Spree.config do |config|
  config.allow_ssl_in_production = false
end`
to the spree.rb initializer

Comment: I hope that you're not planning on running a store in production without SSL. That's not a very good idea.

Comment: I know, I'm using this as a staging environment